# Aligning logo to center with Material-UI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Trying to center a logo in my log in form with `Material-UI`, everything else appears to be centered exception of the logo which is hugging the left side of the card.

I've tried adding `align="center"` and `justify="center"` under the img tag but it still is not moving the image in the center of the card. I've also tried adding a "gridItem" `alignItems:'center'` under my const styles

```
const styles = theme => ({
    logo: {
        padding: "1rem",
        width: 300,
        [theme.breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
            width: 200,
        }
    },

    appName: {
        color: '#2979ff',
        [theme.breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
            fontSize: theme.typography.h5.fontSize
        }
    },
});
```

```
<Grid container justify="center" alignItems="center">
    <Grid item>
    <Card>
    <Grid item> 
    <img className={classes.logo} alt="Portal Logo" src={Logo} align="center" />
</Grid>
```

I am expecting the logo to be centered in my my "login" form that I've created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `flexbox` so better to use `justifyContent: center;` on parent element like .

```html
<Grid container justify="center" alignItems="center">
    <Grid item>
    <Card>
    <Grid item justifyContent="center"> 
    <img className={classes.logo} alt="Portal Logo" src={Logo} align="center" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try text-align:center for the parent element of logo

HTML

```
<div class="logo">
  <img src="logo.png">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.logo{
   text-align:center;
}
```